# Spring YARN: How to create a Tracking UI and correctly wire a proxy to it?

Tags: spring, hadoop-yarn

I want to deploy an application with a web interface. I want to use Spring YARN for this because that eases all the basic setup, and I can start the application with `java -jar`.

What steps do I have to do to:

1. have my application expose a web interface
2. have the tracking URI I get when submitting it proxy to that web interface

Unfortunately, I cannot find anything about this on the net, there is npthing on that particular issue in the Spring documentation and Google searches do not get me the correct results either.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is simply use Spring YARN Boot application model and framework is then trying to do the heavy lifting on your behalf. I actually showed a demo of this during my session at SpringOne 2GX 2014. You can find my session recording from youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlvX7_r9aUA.

Interesting stuff for this particular feature is at the end (starting from 1:16:22) and you can see how web server address is registered into YARN resource manager and how I query it using a Spring YARN Boot CLI (around 1:32:13). Spring YARN will actually see that there is an embedded servlet context and registers it automatically. In this demo property "server.port=0" makes tomcat to choose random port which is then registered.

Code for this particular UI demo can be found from github https://github.com/SpringOne2GX-2014/JanneValkealahti-SpringYarn/tree/master/gs-yarn-rabbit. Demo was around RabbitMQ just to have some real UI functionality and not just a dummy hello world page.

There's also more up-to-date sample in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop-samples/tree/master/boot/yarn-store-groups which doesn't have a real UI(just Boot management endpoints). Thought it's relatively easy to add Spring MVC magic there just by following normal Boot functionality(i.e. following https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service).

Lemmy know if this helps!